# How do i fix the Gallery Slider?

Tags: html, css, image-gallery

I bought a tempalte website for a friend since i am no coder and tried to customize as far as possible.

This is the URL:
http://www.roxaneroffler.com

I have a problem with the gallery, it gets buggy when i add more than 6 or 7 images. It jumps from one image to the beginning and going back behaves weird as well.

I have no idea where to start.
Can you guys check the CSS code through the given website or do i have to post the CSS class? im afraid the horizontal gallery css class is too big.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Unfortunately this isn't a free code service. You might check out the help topic on how to create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and come on back when you have a more concise code related question about your attempts. PS - if you paid for the template, they should offer support for what you purchased. Cheers!

Comment: I see, the site does not have support for the site :/ so i guess i have to get into css. I have two files, a plugin.css and a main.css - i see a lot of lines for a horinzontal slider on the main.css - i guess thats where i should start?

Comment: That's a broad one to speculate on considering what you describe, could be something in the CSS, the HTML, or if it's made with Javascript or JQuery or something. Hard to say.